# How to manage data in a React/Redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux

I having some issues on how to conceptualize a react application with Redux being my Flux library of choice.
So I am taking a few assumptions from my readings, correct me if I am wrong,

How does one manage data fetching? 
Let's say this, I have a application that needs to fetch some data specific for the current logged in user, I assume this user data should be stored in the Redux Store.

But now the problem ensues, if all my state data is stored in a store, do I have for example a array of messages in the store for this user,  and make my component fetch the information from the store? Or should I Fetch the data on the componentWillMount or similar method? I get that when I need to fetch data the first time, I will send an action to the store to fetch the data from the server, which will trigger a change event that I can catch on the component and update the state, is that a correct?

I feel like I am missing a point somewhere and can't make the connection on how the app is supposed to be structured and manage the data, since it seems the store will be bloated with tons of smaller "state" objects that will be used across the other routes/components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Redux` you have a single `store` with many `reducers`. Each `reducer` changes specific part of the `state`.

For example you have an `state` like this:

```
{
    messages: [...],
    currentUser: {...},
    notifications: [...],
    ...
}
```

In this case you will have a `reducer` to change `messages` part of `state`. Another `reducer` to change `notifications` part.

Comment: So when I fetch the messages from the server, then I populate the messages object and use it in my components? So my components fetch data from that store object, and when I need to "refetch" I just update that object correct?

Comment: @Morphex: Yeah, exactly.